# How do you get from experimental measurements to models?

Tags: measurement, modeling

Many analytical models in the literature are *"based on empirical measurements"*.

For example, for a radio propagation model, one would go out in the field, take his equipment and perform *a lot* of measurements in different setups. The output of these measurements would be logged somewhere as a set of point cooridinates,

$$ \{(y_1, x_1),(y_2, x_2), ...(y_n, x_n), ...(y_N, x_N)\} \quad \text{for} \quad 1 \le n \le N $$... Then? What is next?

**What is the step between the raw measurement (empirical) data to the analytical formula? Statistical and visualization of the data, maybe?**

If we assume we have the formula below:

$$ y = f(x) = a b^x + c $$

how do you come up with the \$a\$, the \$b\$, and the \$c\$, and how do you know which component should be additive, which one exponential and and which one multiplied?

**NOTE:** I am aware that this question might not fit 100% to this SE forum, please suggest another one where I can get a useful answer

Comment: Harald Friis actually came up with the radio propagation model based on clear thinking and sound maths (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_T._Friis). As for converting raw data to a formula you just do some suck-it-and-see curve fitting in something like excel. Friis equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation

Comment: _curve fitting_ seem to be the buzzword here?

Comment: You collect data, graph it, and see if there are any easy to see trends. Based on that, you try fitting the data to existing mathematical descriptions, like sines/exponentials...etc. This is more of the intuitive method. Otherwise, you do more complex mathematics to develop the model, trying to get an equation that roughly fits what you have, compare to the real data, add more to get a closer approximation... Iterate until you are satisfied.

Comment: @JarrodChristman feel free to add it as an answer (preferably expand a bit with some references), I would be glad to accept the answer

Comment: There isn't a particular step that you can mechanize. It's human judgement.

Answer (score 1):

You question confuses a bunch of things. Yes, there are [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) methods that minimize the error. That's what you [or software like MODPEX] use[s] to generate the SPICE parameters that best represent a set of device curves that were measured. But note that the model/equations is/are determined beforehand.

However you need a model that has some theoretical basis before you fit some data to it. There's no cookbook method for coming up with the latter although some things like [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) help. But dimensional analysis can't tell you if you should have \$(V_1-V_2)\$ or \$\sqrt{V_1^2+V_2^2}\$ in your formula; both are measured in volts. To decide between something like these you need some deeper theoretical basis [which is domain dependent]; and hopefully it agrees with the experimental evidence.

If you're going to have a model that's purely empirical, i.e.
has no theoretical basis and is just based on prior measurements,
you need to understand the risks/uncertainty involved in such a
model, like the distinction between sample and population. See for
example http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610849.pdf for more (particularly pp. 103-104).
Probably the best place to ask for more is the https://stats.stackexchange.com/ site. Such
purely empirical models are more common in social sciences.